# Facebook (FQL) - How can I sort wall posts by Most Recent and/or Top stories

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am using FQL and now I have the following fql queries:

First one: query get's all my wall posts that shared by my friends (it's working fine):

```
SELECT type, source_id, share_count, permalink, description, post_id, actor_id, target_id, message  
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id in (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me())
```

Second one: query get's all my wall posts that shared by my liked pages (it's working fine):

```
SELECT type, source_id, share_count, permalink, description, post_id, actor_id, target_id, message 
FROM stream
WHERE filter_key = 'others'
```

and now every thing is okay,

so my question is

"Is there any way to sort that posts by [Most Recent or Top stories] either by FQL or Graph API?"

Thank you so much in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These is how I would do the most recent

```
SELECT 
    type, source_id, share_count, permalink, description, 
    post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, created_time
FROM 
    stream 
WHERE 
    source_id in (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me())
ORDER BY
    created_time desc

SELECT 
    type, source_id, share_count, permalink, description, 
    post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, created_time
FROM 
    stream
WHERE 
    filter_key = 'others'
ORDER BY
    created_time desc
```

but regarding top stories I don't think there is a way to do it, but you most likely have to develop your own criteria for the posts you want to see as top and make a query based on that, you may find [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) page useful in your quest

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer that help me a lot I didn't know about 


order by statement 

but still the top stories issue not resolved 

I think there is an enum or some thing hidden that get that list

Comment: Honestly i didn't either, i just tested it with your query and replied  :)